# If I select an area at the centre of the screen, the rectangle is drawn at somewhere above and towards left of actual points

Tags: android, opencv

I am developing an Opencv based android application. In this application I want the user to select an ROI (region of interest) on
the image displayed. These ROI coordinates will be passed to the opencv C++ code to draw a rectangle on the image. 
Problem: There seem to be an offset between the ROI points selected (touched) on the screen and the place where actual 
rectangle is drawn by Opencv. For e.g. if I select an area at the centre of the screen, the rectangle is drawn 
at somewhere above and towards left of actual points.

Note: I do not want to use the native android library to draw this rectangle because this coordinates
will further be used do some image processing within this ROI.I have got co-ordinate from android with this coordinate I want to draw rectangle

Comment: Can you include some code in your question? This is the least we need to get any clue about the problem.

Comment: @Zaphod I am passing co-ordinate which I got from android into opencv now using this co-ordiante I am drawing a rectangle.The rectangle is not drawing at proper place.what should I need to implement